# bridge messes up serial.print

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-yun

**EDIT**
I am using an Genuino Uno & Yun Shield

I am a complete arduino noob

I am creating something where I need a process to execute a command on my yun shield but when I use `Bridge.begin();` It scrambles all text to something like this

> .ÿš2%š%šr%š%š%šr%š2%š2%º%š%š%š2%º2%º2%ºr%š2%º2%šr%šr%š%š2%šþøøþøøþúøøýýøþþþýþþøøøøúýøþÿøøþþøúýþúøøøþøýøþýúøþþøüþþøýþþøýøúø

and it just keeps adding characters. if I don't use `Bridge.begin();` then it correctly prints.

I wrote this short program to replicate the bug:

```
#include <Process.h>

void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:
// Start the bridge and serial port.
Bridge.begin();
Serial.begin(9600);

 while(!Serial){

 }
}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
Serial.println("test");
}
```

So this will give the scrambled text and when you remove the `Bridge.begin();` it will show the text but I really need to use a Process in my other program so as I understand I need Bridge.

Comment: Did you really follow the ["Arduino - Process - Tutorial"](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Process) ?

Comment: If I use that code I get a SerialUSB not declared in this scope on the last line but if change all of them to Serial then it still gives the scrambled output

Comment: This may well not be workable with an Uno as the host, unless you do some serious revision to the behind-the-scenes code, as it probably assumes that there is UART for communication with the Linux module that is distinct from the USB channel to the serial monitor.  That would be true on the Leonardo type system this originated with, but *not* on an Uno.  Hence your probably probably comes from the Bridge code setting the single serial port to a different rate than you intended to use.

Comment: So @ChrisStratton do you maybe have an idea how I could make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `Console` class instead of `Serial`. Official example [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ConsoleRead).

Comment: How can I then view my console because I constantly get "Connection closed by foreign host" on my serial monitor when I connect to the yun shield port in the ide (because it said to do that in the example)

Comment: Have you shorted the two pins on Arduino Board? If you don't know what I'm talking about I will give more information.

Comment: No I have not I was really hoping I wouldn't need to do that where can I find something to sort them?

Comment: And maybe also what pins do I exactly need to sort?

Comment: Well, I realized that wouldn't probably be the problem (I had to do it, but I have the old Dragino Yun Shield, so it doesn't matter in your case, probably). But make sure you are not connected to the Arduino by USB cable, but via WiFi.

Comment: Well that's a little bit of a problem considering that is my power source

Comment: Ok, but make sure in your Arduino IDE you have the *Network Port (with IP address)* selected, NOT the COM ports.

Comment: Yes I am connected through the network

Comment: I found this: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoYunShield#toc10. So if you are using Arduino UNO or MEGA, you need to short the pins indeed.

Comment: How can I sort these then? they say with a jumper but when I google them I only find jumper wires?

Comment: In my case the shunt jumpers were included with the shield, but here are some places where you can get one: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9044, https://www.pololu.com/product/968, http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sullins-connector-solutions/STC02SYAN/S9000-ND/76372. I hope they are the right dimension.

Comment: But if I read that text it says I would still be able to work without the jumper. But my problem is that it says Connection closed by foreign host

Comment: I found a jumper in an old pc thanks for the help

Comment: Great, does it work correctly now?

Answer (score 1):

`Bridge` and `Serial` both use the same pins. You cannot use them both.

`Bridge` runs at a much higher baud rate (230400 IIRC) than `Serial`, which is why it all messes up.

Comment: Do you maybe have an idea why my console says Connection closed by foreign host when I try to view it.